# CodeIgniter session library - potentially dangerous behavior?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, cookies

According to the documentation (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html), the CodeIgniter session library has the following behavior:

"When a page is loaded, the session class will check to see if valid session data exists in the user's session cookie. If sessions data does not exist (or if it has expired) a new session will be created and saved in the cookie. If a session does exist, its information will be updated and the cookie will be updated. With each update, the session_id will be regenerated."

I think this behavior can be dangerous from a security point of view, because somebody could flood the site with requests and that way pollute the session store (which, in my case, is a mysql database). And my app is running on an ordinary web host..

Is there any easy solution to this which does not require too much additional coding? Maybe a library that could substitute for the one that ships with the core? I don't want to code it all myself because I think that would defend the purpose of using a framework.. and I actually don't want to use another PHP framework, since, for my specific requirements, CI is perfect as regards the freedom it gives you...

Comment: What sort of behavior are you seeing ?

Answer (score 1):

> because somebody could flood the site with requests and that way pollute the session store

So? Then you just have a bunch of sessions in the db. This doesn't affect the validity of sessions. If there is a mechanism to delete old session based on space/time, then those sessions are gone and the former owners of those sessions will need to re-authenticate.

If you are worried about collisions, do a little research and you will find that any collision probability is a function of the underlying operating system and/or PHP itself, so CodeIgniter can't help you there.

Also, maybe disk space fills up but that is an operations/architecture problem, not a CodeIgniter problem and not a security issue in and of itself.